# Gitlab New File Template

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

On a self hosted gitlab instance, in the web view of a repository it's possible to create a new file. There is also a drop down "Select a template type".

It has entries like `.gitignore` and `LICENSE`.

Is it possible to define a custom file template? I could not find any mentions of it in the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/instance_template_repository.html indicates that it's not possible in cloud gitlab, and that the selection of template types are limited for self-hosted instances :(

Comment: This [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16814) seems to track the feature request.